# Crash on search bar tap

Tags: ios, swift

App crashes when search bar text field is tapped in UIViewController

My ViewController looks like this -

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

let testBaseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

var searchBar = UISearchBar()
var searchImageView   : UIImageView!
var mapView: GMSMapView!
var markers = [GMSMarker]()
var cameraPosition: GMSCameraPosition!
var searchAddress: String!

var mapButton = UIBarButtonItem()
var listButton = UIBarButtonItem()
var filterButton = UIBarButtonItem()
var arrayOfButtons = [AnyObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-37.809487,
        longitude:144.965699, zoom:17.5, bearing:30, viewingAngle:40)
    mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:cameraPosition)

    mapView.delegate = self
    self.view = mapView

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    setUISearchView()

}

//MARK: SearchBar Methods

func setUISearchView(){

    let searchImage = UIImage(named: "search")!

    searchImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: searchImage.size.width, height: searchImage.size.height))
    searchImageView.image = searchImage

    let rightGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showSearchBar")
    searchImageView.addGestureRecognizer(rightGestureRecognizer)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView = searchImageView

}

func setUICancelView(){

    let searchImage = UIImage(named: "cancel")!

    searchImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: searchImage.size.width, height: searchImage.size.height))
    searchImageView.image = searchImage

    let rightGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideSearchBar")
    searchImageView.addGestureRecognizer(rightGestureRecognizer)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView = searchImageView

}


func searchButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    showSearchBar()
}

func showSearchBar() {

    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

    let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField

    textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    searchBar.alpha = 0
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.searchBar.alpha = 1
        self.setUICancelView()
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    })
}

func hideSearchBar() {
    setSearchBarTitle(searchAddress!)

    searchImageView.alpha = 0


    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {

        self.searchBar.hidden =  false
        self.searchBar.alpha = 0
        self.setUISearchView()
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    })
}

//MARK: UISearchBarDelegate
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
     print("search is working ")
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("searchBarCancelButtonClicked!")
    hideSearchBar()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    hideSearchBar()

     // Do something..
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("searchBarTextDidBeginEditing!")
}  

func setSearchBarTitle(streetAddress: NSString){
    //Adding Title Label
    let navigationTitlelabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    navigationTitlelabel.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    navigationTitlelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    navigationTitlelabel.textColor  = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationTitlelabel.text = "streetAddress" as! String
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.titleView = navigationTitlelabel
}

func setSearchBar(){

    // Remove the drop shadow from the navigation bar for distinct status bar
    navigationController!.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true

    navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.candyGreen()
}


//MARK: Other logic
```

}

My Scene looks like this -
[image]

App crashes on device when search bar edit text field is tapped. Though, it works fine if I comment self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() in showSearcBar() resulting in no key for input. Same code works fine on simulator as I can use my development machine keys to enter search bar field.

I'm new to swift development with no previous knowledge of Obj C.

- All UI Controls are vanishing from screen leaving just google map as soon as I tapp search bar edit field*

**EDIT**

Crash Log :

```
Jan 10 23:33:33 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Notice>: CoreLocation: CLPocketStateService 43328.265701: Stationary,1,Orientation,2,Proximity,0,State,1
Jan 10 23:33:35 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Notice>: CoreLocation: CLPocketStateService 43329.719682: Stationary,2,Orientation,2,Proximity,0,State,2
Jan 10 23:33:39 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Notice>: CoreLocation: CLPocketStateService 43333.481776: Stationary,1,Orientation,2,Proximity,0,State,1
Jan 10 23:33:39 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Notice>: CoreLocation: CLPocketStateService 43333.757166: Stationary,1,Orientation,1,Proximity,0,State,3
Jan 10 23:33:41 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image
Jan 10 23:33:41 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Notice>: CoreLocation: CLPocketStateService 43336.076814: Stationary,1,Orientation,2,Proximity,0,State,1
Jan 10 23:33:42 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Jan 10 23:33:42 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Notice>: CoreLocation: CLPocketStateService 43336.927797: Stationary,2,Orientation,2,Proximity,0,State,2
Jan 10 23:33:50 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Disabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning off.
Jan 10 23:33:50 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone backboardd[56] <Notice>: [HID] [MT] MTSimpleHIDManager::setPropertyInternal detection mode: 3->255 
Jan 10 23:33:50 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 54 sel: 26 ret: e00002e2 '-536870174')
Jan 10 23:33:50 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Error>:  LockStateNotifier aksNotificationCallback posting notification: com.apple.mobile.keybagd.lock_status
Jan 10 23:33:50 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Notice>: (Note ) PIH: Lock status changed.
Jan 10 23:33:51 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone MobileMail[165] <Warning>: Key bag transitioning from unlocked to locking
Jan 10 23:33:51 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: [autosu error]: SPI for AutoSU: unable to find bestSuStart or bestSuEnd with corresponding prob above desired threshold
Jan 10 23:33:51 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone com.apple.CDScheduler[23] <Error>: AutoSu doesn't have any prediction yet
Jan 10 23:33:51 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone com.apple.CDScheduler[23] <Error>: Failed to get device restart forecast
Jan 10 23:33:51 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Jan 10 23:33:51 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone wirelessproxd[55] <Notice>: (Error) updateScanner - central is not powered on: 4
Jan 10 23:34:00 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleKeyStore:Sending lock change 1 for handle 0
Jan 10 23:34:00 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Error>:  LockStateNotifier aksNotificationCallback posting notification: com.apple.mobile.keybagd.lock_status
Jan 10 23:34:00 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Notice>: (Note ) PIH: Lock status changed.
Jan 10 23:34:00 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone MobileMail[165] <Warning>: Key bag transitioning from locking to locked
Jan 10 23:34:13 Atul-Kaushiks-iPhone syncdefaultsd[815] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x12ee0b070>
```

Comment: add an exception breakpoint. See what gets hit while crashing. Also use breakpoints to do step by step debug .

Comment: try to nslog the searchImageView frame, and see if it prints something.

Comment: Are we talking about dimensions? I am getting valid dims for searchImageView. I have no experience in Objective-C hence please let me know if I am wrong here.

Comment: Could you please attach the crash report?

Comment: @return false I have attached the crash log. Please let me know in case you need whole class / more logs

Comment: Ran into a similar issue a while ago.  My issue was the content I was searching through was not fully loaded yet.  Confirm that your content is all present before making your searchbar enabled?

Comment: @ joels Can you please give me a hint how can I check if it's loaded or not?
What calls do I need to make to ascertain that content has been loaded. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @kaushik After looking further at your crash log, I see no reason why it would be the cause the crash.  My experience was actually upon typing into the search bar, not when the search bar would become the first responder.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `searchAddress` is declared as implicit unwrapped optional.

When the search bar button is clicked the method `hideSearchBar()` is called and `searchAddress` is unwrapped. That causes the crash because `searchAddress` is `nil`.

Solution: Declare `searchAddress` as non optional and initialize it with an empty string.

```
var searchAddress = ""
```

and remove the exclamation mark

```
setSearchBarTitle(searchAddress)
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian but I'm still getting the crash. It's happening immediately after soft keys becomes visible for a fraction of time. Moreover, if this is the reason, then it should not work on simulator.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and check if `searchImageView` is `nil` when the exception is raised.

Comment: @vadian's answer was correct. You must be getting a crash from somewhere else

Comment: @Ducky I have added the crash log also. I have used Vadian's solution but of no help. Am struggling with my limited knowledge. All UI Controls are vanishing from screen leaving just google map as soon as I tapp search bar edit field

Comment: Share your GitHub repo plz

Answer (score 2):

**Crash Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

I  try  to use you code, when i tap cancel ,  the  app  crash and i found the searchAddress is nil, but you 'setSearchBarTitle(searchAddress!)', so  crash.

I suggest set the searchAddress is optional value, that is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code by myself while removing the Google Maps view, and didn't run into any crashes.

Maybe there is an issue with Google maps view and UISearchField, so please try to **temporarily remove** the Google maps views by excluding `self.view = mapView`, and give feedback whether it works using the comment section below.